# Audio is not working when it is included inside another PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, audio

I have a PHP file with an `audio` tag that works just fine when executed. It is like this:

```
<?php
  echo"<audio controls>";
  echo"<source src='victory.mp3' type='audio/mp3'>";
  echo"</audio>";   
?>
```

The HTML file with the same functionality works well when executed. However I need to include this file in another PHP file inside a function. Like this:

```
function play_music()
{
  include('temp.php');
}
```

Running the above code just gives an `audio` player, but it won't start as the audio length is shown as `00:00`. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

I've tested in Chrome, IE and Firefox and the `audio` tag is compatible with these versions. Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the console, I would guess it's a path problem, ie. the `victory.mp3` file is in another folder from where you're attempting to use it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is right, seems to be a path problem. Do inspect element and check the path

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No I've placed the file in the same folder as php files.

Comment: Did you at least check the console for errors?

Comment: Do you have the second PHP file in the same path as the first that works?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes it says failed to load resource, although I have the mp3 file in the same folder

Comment: @GonzaloPani Yes all these files are in the same folder

Comment: You may believe that to be the case, but the server clearly does not. This is a path issue, which we cannot really offer you any help with. You just need to use the correct one.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Try to use full path like: http://www.example.com/victory.mp3

Comment: @KomalRangoonwala you can also use onerror event attribute to your audio tag for alert/console the message

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing your above mention code it's working fine just check this.
temp.php code

```
<?php echo"<audio controls> <source src='Valentines.mp3' type='audio/mp3'> </audio>";   ?>
```

Function File Code it's also show called function in same file. check your path if your temp file and function file not in same folder give audio path according to function file path. I'm try all file with same folder.

```
<?php function play_music(){ include('temp.php'); } echo play_music(); ?>
```

if your audio file save in same folder where store temp.php and function file is an other folder you use audio file path according to function file path. like you have Music folder and that have temp file and audio file and other have function folder where you store all function then you set you audio path like this ../music/vectory.mp3

Comment: Well thanks for trying I guess I have the wrong path. It says it does not have access to load resources. I'm using WordPress btw.

Comment: in WordPress all media save in one place use complete URL in path. i hope it's help full for you

Comment: Okay, I'll try a couple of different workarounds and see if I can get it working on WordPress. Thanks! :)